# Is there anyway to get the location of solr conf folder in java through any api.

Tags: java, solr

I want to read the stopword.txt file present in the conf folder using my custom update handler. However I cannot implement the interface ResourceLoaderAware as they can only be used with some certain class and not UpdateRequestProcessorFactory class. So i was thinking if i could get the location of the conf , then i can read the file directly from java buffered reader.

Comment: System.getProperty("solr.conf.dir") and then open it with any FileReader?

Comment: System.getProperty("solr.conf.dir") gives me null value.

Comment: Actually, it was the direction, where you need to look.
Anyway, try this - "solr.solr.home" this is Solr homem, you will need go depeer to read your file

Comment: thanks. even i got it now. i am using that to reach that folder and then traversing on my own.

Comment: I could post it as answer, if it really helps you

Answer (score 1):

Starting from solr 4.7 you can read all configuration files using http requests. For example:

```
http://yourhost:8983/solr/yourcore/admin/file?file=stopwords.txt
```

Comment: Like that way. But what about security constrains? Usually, Solr are behind firewalls, so that clients couldn't have direct access.